# getting null pass String from fragment to the activiy using bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

Well this will sound silly but I am using bundle to store my Data within, and trying to pass this bundle from the fragment to the hosting activity, and testing the data using a toast, but the toast is empty! I cant find the reason why this is happening since i made sure to fill the data correctly
My code in the fragment is:

```
 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent_register, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setUpViews();
        setRecyclerAdapter();
    }

    private void setUpViews() {
        fullNameEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_parent_register_fullName);
        emailEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_parent_register_email);
        passwordEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_parent_register_password);
        fullName = fullNameEditText.getText().toString();
        email= emailEditText.getText().toString();
        password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        Bundle parentData = new Bundle();
        parentData.putString(KEY_PARENT_FULL_NAME,fullName);
        parentData.putString(KEY_PARENT_EMAIL,email);
        parentData.putString(KEY_PARENT_PASSWORD,password);

        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        intent.putExtras(parentData);
```

in the activity is :

```
  registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (DataHolder.getInstance().getAccountType() == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, TeacherLocationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                /*    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, StudentLocationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);*/
                    Bundle parentData = getIntent().getExtras();
                    if (parentData != null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, parentData.getString(KEY_PARENT_FULL_NAME)+parentData.getString(KEY_PARENT_EMAIL)+parentData.getString(KEY_PARENT_PASSWORD), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (parentData == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Bundle is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetupViews` is executed right after views are created, which means they are most likelly empty. You need to first make `onClickListener` that sets the data after the user fills it in. The other code seems to be correct

Comment: you are right, the data taken from the editTexts were filled at the creation of the fragment and not after he user fills it, so i used editText.setOnFocusChangeListener for each one and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this for send data from Fragment:-

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),YourActivityName.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_PARENT_FULL_NAME,fullName);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_PARENT_EMAIL,email);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_PARENT_PASSWORD,password);
```

try this for getting data in Activity:-

```
String data=this.getIntent().getStringextra(KEY_PARENT_FULL_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from fragment to activity, you should use OnFragmentInteractionListener. Go to Android studio, add new fragment to see how is it implemented. It's very easy.

Read here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html